# Why does data from a model not render in an Ember template's {{#each}} loop?

Tags: ember.js

Data that seems successfully loaded into my model does not seem to be used when rendering a page template in Ember 2.1.0.  How can I get the data that is shown to me in Ember Inspector to be successfully called by the page template?

I have a model:

```
  App.Part = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    summary: DS.attr('string')
  });

  App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({  
    model: function() }
     return this.store.findAll('part')
    }
  });
```

and a template:

```
{{appName}} v {{appVersion}}
<ul>
  {{#each part in model}}
        <li>{{part.name}}</li>
    {{else}}
        none found...
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

and in my Ember Inspector I see data (loaded via RESTAdapter):
[image: Data properly loaded loaded with unique IDs and part names]

But the template when rendered always says, "none found..." and never lists the data that appears to have been successfully loaded. I have tried multiple variations of the {{#each}} tag.

A standard app controller loads data into the template just fine (calling {{appName}} or {{appVersion}}):

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: "My App",
  appVersion: "1.0",
});
```

Ember 2.1.0, EmberData 2.1.0, EmberInspector 1.9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `application` template won't show the model for the `index` route.

Change `App.IndexRoute` to `App.ApplicationRoute`.

Alternatively, you can split your template up:

application.hbs

```
{{appName}} v {{appVersion}}

{{outlet}}
```

index.hbs

```
<ul>
  {{#each part in model}}
        <li>{{part.name}}</li>
    {{else}}
        none found...
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with a single app.js file no matter how well the template/routes were aligned. However, when I used ember-cli and parsed up the app into separate files, your suggestion worked perfectly.  And in fact, it did require the `app` OR `index` route/template/etc showing the data be consistent with the same space loading the data.